# How to read information from file using regex and print it?

Tags: regex, perl

I am working with the following data:

```
__DATA__
Branch 1: 10..11

      13 E 0.496 -> Q 0.724
      18 S 0.507 -> R 0.513
      19 N 0.485 -> S 0.681

Branch 2: 11..12

      81 R 0.891 -> Q 0.639
      88 Y 0.987 -> S 0.836
```

From the above data, I want to read numbers present before a character and then print them out. So for instance in *Branch 1* I want to read **13** , **18**, **19** and from *Branch 2*, I want to read **81** **88**.

I have written the following code for reading Branch 1 but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $find = 'Branch 1:';
$a = '0';

open (FILE, "/user/Desktop/file") || die "can't open file \n";
while (my $body = <FILE>) {
    if ($body =~ m/$find/) {
        my $value = my $body=~ m/\d{2}\s[A-Z]/;
        print "$value \n";
    }
    else {
        $a++; # only to check it reading anything
        print "$a \n";
    }
}
__END__
```

Comment: Don't use $a (and $b): Because of their special status as sort variables, they are exempt from strict checks and subject to action at a distance.

Comment: You are reading the file line-by-line. Therefore, when $body (which in fact is just a line) contains 'Branch 1', it will not contain the number you want. Also, if you want to keep track of how many lines you have read, use $.

Comment: ALERT: This is a homework assignment and should not receive a fully coded solution.  Please can we just point the OP to the relevant help docs?

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    if ( /^(Branch [0-9]+): / or /^\s+([0-9]+) [A-Z]/ ) {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
Branch 1: 10..11

      13 E 0.496 -> Q 0.724
      18 S 0.507 -> R 0.513
      19 N 0.485 -> S 0.681

Branch 2: 11..12

      81 R 0.891 -> Q 0.639
      88 Y 0.987 -> S 0.836
```

Answer (score 2):

```
m/\d{2}\s[A-Z]0/
```

should be

```
m/\d{2}\s[A-Z]/
```

or possibly

```
m/\d{2}\s[A-Z]\s0/
```

or even

```
m/\d{2}\s[A-Z]\s\d/
```

The point being that your code is expecting a `0` immediately after the letter, but there is a space inbetween.

Comment: i have updated my code but it still doesn't seem to work. It is still going to else statement.

Answer (score 0):

one thing is that you do not have a space between your [A-Z] and the 0