# How can I find all matches to a regular expression in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have text in the form:

```
Name=Value1
Name=Value2
Name=Value3
```

Using Perl, I would like to match `/Name=(.+?)/` every time it appears and extract the (.+?) and push it onto an array. I know I can use `$1` to get the text I need and I can use `=~` to perform the regex matching, but I don't know how to get all matches.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034027/how-do-i-access-captured-substrings-after-a-successful-regex-match-in-perl

Answer (score 55, accepted):

A `m//g` in list context returns all the captured matches.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $str = <<EO_STR;
Name=Value1
Name=Value2
Name=Value3
EO_STR

my @matches = $str =~ /=(\w+)/g;
# or my @matches = $str =~ /=([^\n]+)/g;
# or my @matches = $str =~ /=(.+)$/mg;
# depending on what you want to capture

print "@matches\n";
```

However, it looks like you are parsing an INI style configuration file. In that case, I will recommend [Config::Std](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Config::Std).

Comment: The important thing to note is the `g` at the end of the regular expression.

Comment: Actually, I simplified the format. There's text in the middle, but until I handled the simple case, there was no hope of me handling the larger case.

Answer (score 9):

```
my @values;
while(<DATA>){
  chomp;
  push @values, /Name=(.+?)$/;
}   
print join " " => @values,"\n";

__DATA__
Name=Value1
Name=Value2
Name=Value3
```

Comment: Don't use $1 if the regex didn't succeed: `/Name=(.+?)$/ and push @values, $1`.   Or even just `my @values = map /Name=(.+?)$/, <DATA>;`

Answer (score 5):

The following will give all the matches to the regex in an array.

```
push (@matches,$&) while($string =~ /=(.+)$/g );
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a regular expression you might prefer trying a grammar engine like:

- [`Parse::RecDescent`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parse-RecDescent/)
- [`Regexp::Grammars`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Grammars/)

I've given a snippet of a [Parse::ResDescent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160889/emulation-of-lex-like-functionality-in-perl-or-python/161977#161977) answer before on SO. However Regexp::Grammars looks very interesting and is influenced by [Perl6 rules & grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_6_rules).

So I thought I'd have a crack at Regexp::Grammars ;-)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $text = q{
Name=Value1
Name = Value2
Name=Value3  
};

my $grammar = do {
    use Regexp::Grammars;
    qr{
        <[VariableDeclare]>*

        <rule: VariableDeclare>
            <Var> \= <Value>

        <token: Var>    Name

        <rule: Value>   <MATCH= ([\w]+) >
    }xms;
};


if ( $text =~ $grammar ) {
    my @Name_values = map { $_->{Value} } @{ $/{VariableDeclare} };
    say "@Name_values";
}
```

The above code outputs `Value1 Value2 Value3`.

Very nice! The only caveat is that it requires Perl 5.10 and that it may be overkill for the example you provided ;-)

/I3az/

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Config::` module to read configuration data. For something simple like that, I might reach for [ConfigReader::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/ConfigReader::Simple). It's nice to stay out of the weeds whenever you can.