# Linux Bash script to read samba config

Tags: bash, samba

I'm trying to create a bash script that will read the samba config, loop through the different "sections" and act if a variable is set

Here is an example config:

```
[global]
    workgroup = METRAN
    encrypt passwords = yes
    wins support = yes
    log level = 1 
    max log size = 1000
    read only = no
[homes] 
    browsable = no
    map archive = yes
[printers] 
    path = /var/tmp
    printable = yes
    min print space = 2000
[music]
    browsable = yes
    read only = yes
    path = /usr/local/samba/tmp
[pictures]
    browsable = yes
    read only = yes
    path = /usr/local/samba/tmp
    force user = www-data
```

Here is kinda what I want to do (I know this syntax a real language, but it should give you the idea:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
CONFIG='/etc/samba/smb.conf'
sections = magicto $CONFIG    #array of sections
foreach $sections as $sectionname       #loop through the sections
  if $sectionname != ("homes" or "global" or "printers")
    if $force_user is-set
       do something with $sectionname and with $force_user
    endif
    else
       do something with $sectionname
    endelse
  endif
endforeach
```

Comment: if you just need to print output (as your "do something") this would be trivial in awk. Don't have time today. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will read each section and get key,value pair.

```
#!/bin/bash
CONFIG='/etc/samba/smb.conf'
for i in homes music; do
    echo "$i"
    sed -n '/\['$i'\]/,/\[/{/^\[.*$/!p}' $CONFIG | while read -r line; do
        printf "%-15s : %s\n" "${line%?=*}" "${line#*=?}"
    done
done
```

**Output**

```
homes
browsable  : no
map archive : yes
music
browsable  : yes
read only  : yes
path       : /usr/local/samba/tmp
```

**Explanation**

- `sed -n '/\['$i'\]/,/\[/{/^\[.*$/!p}'`

  1) `/\['$i'\]/,/\[/` Matches the section name between `[]` until the next `[`

  2) `{/^\[.*$/!p}` Matches the start of line `^` followed by `[` and zero or more characters `.*` until end of line `$` and if matches don't print `!p`
- `${line%?=*}` Trim string from the end (right) until first `=` and any char `?`
- `${line#*=?}` Trim string from the start (left) until first `=` and any char `?`

Comment: I like this one the best as I want to use this in init.d and it seems simplest.  This is really close.  My 2 issues are: I don't always have the "home" or "music", those could be anything and I need to iterate through them.  Also, they need to be able to use spaces like "My Music"... not sure how to do that.

Comment: Add everything you need to match on the for loop line as sed will not match if not found in file. You can also match a key with spaces via quoting `for i in 'homes' 'My Music'; do`

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub read_conf {
  my $conf_filename = shift;
  my $section;
  my %config;
  open my $cfile, "<", $conf_filename or die ("open '$conf_filename': $!");
  while (<$cfile>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^\[([^]]+)]/) {
      $section = $1; 
    } else {
      my ($k, $v) = split (/\s*=\s*/);
      $k =~ s/^\s*//;
      $config{$section}{$k} = $v; 
    }   
  }
  close $cfile;
  return \%config;
}

sub main {
  my $conf_filename = '/etc/samba/smb.conf';
  my $conf = read_conf($conf_filename);
  foreach my $section (grep { !/homes/ and !/global/ and !/printers/} keys %$conf) {
    print "do something with: $section\n";
    foreach my $key (keys %{$conf->{$section}}) {
      my $val = $conf->{$section}{$key};
      print "$key is $val in $section\n";
    }   
  }
}

main;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with Perl, you might look at Config::Std

http://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Std

Compliments of this question: [How can I find all matches to a regular expression in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723440/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-perl)