# Find regexp matches starting from specific position in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have 2 RegExps. How can I get the start position of first RegExp matched substring and start to find second RegExp matching from this position?

**UPD:** For example:

```
$_ = "
=cut
vffdv
vdfvfd
vdfvfdvfd
=pod
dvfddv
vfdvfdvf
vdfvfdvfd
=end
";
$\ = "\n";

sub get {
 my $_ = shift;
 /=((\d|\w)+)/i;
 return $1;
}


print get($_) while /^=/mg;
```

Prints

```
cut
cut
cut
```

But I need

```
cut
pod
end
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1723458)

Comment: @HamZa But there will be list of `=`. And RegExp from `get` won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending `$_` which doesn't change in `while` loop and it is defined at start of the script to `get()` function.

You need to capture content and send `$1` to function.

```
print get($1) while /^=(.+)/mg;
```

---

Side note; most of the time do prefer named variables over implicit `$_`. Also `my $_ = ..` is asking for trouble if you're expecting dynamic scoping for `$_` global, and lexical `$_` is clobbering it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this

```
$_ = "
=cut
vffdv
vdfvfd
vdfvfdvfd
=pod
dvfddv
vfdvfdvf
vdfvfdvfd
=end
";

my @array = split /\n/ , $_;
for ( @array ){
    if( $_ =~ /^=/ ){
        print substr( $_ , 1 ) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works like I need.

```
$_ = "
=cut
vffdv
vdfvfd
vdfvfdvfd
=pod
dvfddv
vfdvfdvf
vdfvfdvfd
=fuck
";
$\ = "\n";

sub get {
 my $_ = shift;
 my $start = shift;
 pos($_) = $start - 1;
 /=((\d|\w)+)/ig;
 return $1;
}


print get($_,pos $_) while /^=/mg;
```