# Regular expression for match all words without numbers

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
" abalbal asldad  23 sadaskld 3123 adasdas "
```

How to match only the words, without numbers..
with `" \D* "` I can match only the first two, without others..

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/\b[^\d\W]+\b/g
```

to match all words with no digits.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iA5bT1/1)

`[^\d\W]` will match any non-digit and (non-non-word) i.e. a word character.

Answer (score 8):

I'd use this one:

```
/\b([a-z]+)\b/gi
```

or, to be unicode compatible

```
/(\p{L}+)/g
```

Answer (score 3):

If the task is to match words that only consist of letters, you can use the following solutions:

- [python](/questions/tagged/python): `r'\b[^\W\d_]+\b'` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gd6Czb/1))
- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript): `/\b\p{Alphabetic}+\b/gu` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gd6Czb/2)) **NOTE**: requires *ECMAScript 2018+* support.
- [php](/questions/tagged/php): `'~\b\p{L}+\b~u'` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gd6Czb/3))
- [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby): `/\b\p{L}+\b/` (see [demo](https://rubular.com/r/xoQHZtpcQPqyXZ))
- [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23): `@"\b\p{L}+\b"` (see demo)
- [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net): `"\b\p{L}+\b"` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/EAtt4y))
- [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b): `R"(\b[[:alpha:]]+\b)"` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/UU4k94)) **NOTE**: Only ASCII letters are considered word chars.
- [r](/questions/tagged/r): `"(*UCP)\\b\\p{L}+\\b"` for base R function with `perl=TRUE` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/OrBoqT)) or just `"\\b\\p{L}+\\b"` for *stringr* regex functions
- [lua](/questions/tagged/lua): `"%f[%a]%a+%f[%A]"` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/iAHvFA))**NOTE**: Only ASCII letters are considered word chars.
- [gnu-sed](/questions/tagged/gnu-sed): `sed -E 's/\b[[:alpha:]]+\b/DELETED/g' file` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/hxOqmf))
- [gnu-grep](/questions/tagged/gnu-grep): `grep -oE '\b[[:alpha:]]+\b' file` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/hxOqmf))
- [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl): `set pattern {\y[[:alpha:]]+\y}` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/C4Zn2C))

Note that most PCRE-based or PCRE-originated regex flavors use `\b` to match leading/trailing word boundaries. PostgreSQL and Tcl use `\y` instead of `\b`. There are other types of word boundaries, like `\m` (Tcl, PostgreSQL), or `\<` (Vim, GNU sed or grep, base R), or `[[:<:]]` (MacOS FreeBSD grep/sed, MySQL up tp v6, base R with `perl=TRUE`, PCRE in general) to match a leading word boundary and `\M`, or `\>`, or `[[:>:]]` accordingly to match closing, or trailing, word boundary.

Comment: May you please add regex for `perl`?

Comment: @EugenKonkov Perl pattern to match a letter-only word is `\b\p{L}+\b`. You may use it in the matching or replacing context, but the final solution will depend on what you actually are doing. Also, see [How can I find all matches to a regular expression in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1723440/3832970)

Answer (score 0):

This expression worked for me:

```
/[a-zA-Z]+'?[a-zA-Z]+/g
```

Not only it matches all the words and ignores the numbers, it also gets words like "he's", "we're", "what's", "Bruce's".