# REGEX for selecting only words in a paragraph

Tags: regex, angular2-directives

I want to write a JAVASCRIPT regex for selecting the words with only **alphabet** characters in the paragraph.

eg.

Input = My name is Apple iPhone 6S. My price is dollar 499. My RAM is 2GB.
Output = 
**My/name/is/Apple/iPhone/My/price/is/dollar/My/RAM/is**

I know that the regex is used for the pattern matching not for making the runtime decisions based on the pattern. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression for match all words without numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375632/regular-expression-for-match-all-words-without-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

You can use word boundaries, such as:

```
(\b[a-zA-Z]+)
```

to only match words with letters from a-z and A-Z.