# Simple XQuery FLWOR to return text without numbers

Tags: regex, xml, xquery, basex, flwor

How do I return non-numeric text?

```
for $foo  in db:open("foo")
return $foo//text()
```

Assuming that every address or phone number cell from the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60221464/262852) spreadsheet has numerals, I'm looking to return any string [without](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29375632/262852) numerals.

---

context, per Michael Kay's note:

Each cell of the spreadsheet has a String.  There's only one column of what can easily be `CSV` data.  Seemingly, only the names lack numerals.  On that assumption, looking to break the data into "chunks" to differentiate each individual.  There's no real pattern to the data.

Comment: It seems a strange requirerment. You really want to return "Rose Cottage, Oak Lane", but not "Rose Cottage, 13 Oak Lane"?

Comment: In short, @MichaelKay :  "yes".  I added an explanatory note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm looking to return any string without numerals.

Regex could do that:

```
for $foo in db:open("foo")
return $foo//text()[not(matches(., '[0-9]'))]
```