# How to pipe one FLWOR into another?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery, flwor

Simple `FLWOR` to get all the data (from what [was](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60221464/262852) a spreadsheet):

```
for $foo  in db:open("foo")
return $foo//text()
```

gives this type of output:

```
...    
Smallville, XX 12345-1234
Bob 
(123) 456-7809
(123) 876-3468
Smallville, XX 12345-1234
Alice
Smallville, XX 12345-1234
Fred
(123) 654-5432
Smallville, XX 12345-1234
...
```

and another which [returns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60223486/262852) non-numeric data:

```
for $foo  in db:open("foo")
return $foo//text()[not(matches(., '[0-9]'))]
```

Which *seems* to return only the names.  On that assumption, looking to trigger closing tags on a `<person>` and opening a new `<person>`, like:

```
<person>
<name>a</name>
<data>123</data>
<data>345</data>
<data>123 main st</data>
</person>

<person>
...
</person>
```

Or something like that.  Only really looking to seperate individuals on the *assumption* that there aren't numerals in their name, and then creating some sort of entity in `XML`.

Just so long as each time a "name" is found that triggers closing tags and then "starting" a new person.  Not at all sure of the standard lingo here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following creates a temporary XML structure, then iterates through each of the `name` elements, creating a `person` with the `name` and it's `following-sibling::data` elements.

```
let $temp := 
  <doc>{
    for $foo in db:open("foo")
    return
      if (matches($foo, "[0-9]")) 
      then <data>{$foo}</data>
      else <name>{$foo}</name>
  }</doc>

for $name in $temp/name
return
  <person>{
    $name,
    $name/following-sibling::data[preceding-sibling::name[1]= $name]
  }</person>
```