# Why is Perl not printing all regex matches in a multi-line regex?

Tags: regex, perl, printing, push, tr

I have this text (shortened version of my original text):

> **mytext.txt**
>   BAHJSBUBGUCYHAGSBUCAGSUCBASBCYHUBXZCZPZHCUIHAUISHCIUJXZJCBZYAUSGHDYUAGWEBWHBHJASBHJASCXZBUYTRTRTRJFUARGAFGOOPWWKBBCAAAABBXHABSDAUSBCZAAAAAAAAACGAFAXHJBJHXZCXZCCZCXZUCAGSUCBASBCYHUBXZCZPZHCUIHAUISHCIUJXZJCBZYAUSGHDYUAGWEBWHBHJASBHJASCXZBUYHABSDAUSZXHJBRRRRRRJFUABGAFGLLPKWAACAAAABBZJHXZXHJBJHXZXHJBJHXJBJHXZCXZCCZCXZUCAGSAJIJICXZIJUAUUISUSJUSSJSJSJAJCXZXCZTTTTTRJFUABGAFGLOPKWABCAAAABBU

My code is the following, which intends to print all of the matches and then save them into a file as well. But I am not getting any matches while I except there to be at least 10 in my original file.

```
open(text, "<mytext.txt");

push (@matches,$&) while(<text> =~ m{
    ([TR]{6}
    JFUA
    [ABR]{1}
    GAFG
    ( [LOP]{2,3} )
    [KW]{2,5}
    (??{ $2 =~ tr/LOP/ABC/r })
    AAAABB[UXZ]{1})
    /g
}x);

print "@matches\n";

my $filename = 'results_matches.txt';
open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
print $fh "@matches\n";
close $fh;
print "done\n";
```

**I have also tried the following code and this also does not work:**

```
my @matches = <text> =~ m{
        ([TR]{6}
        JFUA
        [ABR]{1}
        GAFG
        ( [LOP]{2,3} )
        [KW]{2,5}
        (??{ $2 =~ tr/LOP/ABC/r })
        AAAABB[UXZ]{1})
        /g
    }x;

print "@matches\n";
```

**I have the following code which successfully prints out only one (the first) result. But it fails to print all of the matches.**

```
if (<text> =~ m{
    ([TR]{6}
    JFUA
    [ABR]{1}
    GAFG
    ( [LOP]{2,3} )
    [KW]{2,5}
    (??{ $2 =~ tr/LOP/ABC/r })
    AAAABB[UXZ]{1})
}x) {print "$1\n";}
```

I have followed the answers in this topic but have not been able to get any of them to work: [How can I find all matches to a regular expression in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723440/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-perl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `while <text>`, you are reading a new file from the file handle on each iteration of the loop. You need to loops, one iterating over the lines, and the inner loop to iterate over the matches.

```
while (my $line = <text>) {
    push @matches, $1 while $line
        =~ m{
            ([TR]{6}
            JFUA
            [ABR]
            GAFG
            ( [LOP]{2,3} )
            [KW]{2,5}
            (??{ $2 =~ tr/LOP/ABC/r })
            AAAABB[UXZ])
        }xg;
}
```

I also removed `{1}` as it's useless, used $1 instead of $& because $& imposes a performance penatly on all the matching you do in a program; and removed the `/g` and added the `g` to the right place (i.e. next to `}x`).

When testing, I copied'n'pasted the input from here, i.e. I have all the characters in one line. If your input is different, please use the code formatting for it, not quotation.